# Create a lock for a shell script

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, lock

Is there any way to lock a shell script from being executed twice?

I need to execute a script that transfers some files from one server to another. The script has to be executed by cron once a day. The connection between both servers should be fast, but may be slower at some times, meaning that the transfer may take more than 24 hours time. Hence, if the script is still running after 24 hours, cron should not execute it.

I thought of creating a file named myscript.lock at the start of the script and deleting it again at the end of the script execution. When the script is started it first checks if the file exists and if it does, then the script stops. This way I can guarantee only one execution. But, if the server breaks down during the script execution, the file will remain and not be deleted. Hence, every time the script is started it will think that it is already running.

Is there any locking functionality offered by the OS I could use for this matter?

Comment: @ByteCommander The suggestion in your link is to create a lock file. Hence, not a good solution, because as described above, if the server breaks down during script execution, the lock file will remain and the script will think that it is already running.

Comment: How about creating the lock file in the `/tmp` directory, then it'll be deleted when the server is rebooted.

Comment: @Arronical Yeah, this would be a bit better, than just placing the file "anywhere". Still, if the script for any reason is stopped in the middle of its execution without the server OS breaking down, the above mentioned problem still remains.

Comment: Sorry, I misread part of the question. You can use commands like `pgrep` to check if a specific executable is currently running. See `man pgrep` for further information.

Comment: The system offers the [`flock(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/flock.2.html) function, which is used by the [`flock(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/flock.1.html) command. You can use it. You don't need to delete the lock file.

Comment: @ByteCommander The command `pgrep` works well: `pgrep -u myuser scriptname`. Thank you.

Comment: @muru Flock is an elegant solution for locking any script: http://www.kfirlavi.com/blog/2012/11/06/elegant-locking-of-bash-program/ Thank you!